# Vuetify - Don't trigger input on treeview when selection is synced

Tags: vuetify.js

On the vuetify treeview component the @input event is triggered when the selected array is initialised, I don't want this behaviour, I need the input event to be triggered only when the user manually selects/deselects an item

```
<v-treeview
      selectable
      selected-color="red"
      :value="selected"
      :items="items"
       @input="input"
    ></v-treeview>

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    selected: [],
    items: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Applications :',
        children: [
          { id: 2, name: 'Calendar : app' },
          { id: 3, name: 'Chrome : app' },
          { id: 4, name: 'Webstorm : app' },
        ],
      },
      {
        id: 5,
        name: 'Documents :',
        children: [
          {
            id: 6,
            name: 'vuetify :',
            children: [
              {
                id: 7,
                name: 'src :',
                children: [
                  { id: 8, name: 'index : ts' },
                  { id: 9, name: 'bootstrap : ts' },
                ],
              },
            ],
          },
          {
            id: 10,
            name: 'material2 :',
            children: [
              {
                id: 11,
                name: 'src :',
                children: [
                  { id: 12, name: 'v-btn : ts' },
                  { id: 13, name: 'v-card : ts' },
                  { id: 14, name: 'v-window : ts' },
                ],
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        id: 15,
        name: 'Downloads :',
        children: [
          { id: 16, name: 'October : pdf' },
          { id: 17, name: 'November : pdf' },
          { id: 18, name: 'Tutorial : html' },
        ],
      },
      {
        id: 19,
        name: 'Videos :',
        children: [
          {
            id: 20,
            name: 'Tutorials :',
            children: [
              { id: 21, name: 'Basic layouts : mp4' },
              { id: 22, name: 'Advanced techniques : mp4' },
              { id: 23, name: 'All about app : dir' },
            ],
          },
          { id: 24, name: 'Intro : mov' },
          { id: 25, name: 'Conference introduction : avi' },
        ],
      },
    ],
  }),
  mounted() {
    this.selected = [1]
  },
  methods: {
    input() {
      alert("input should not be triggered")// I don't want this to be triggered unless the user explicitly selects/deselects an item
    }
  }
})
```

Here is a codepen with the problem - https://codepen.io/amaieras/pen/yLPLyvZ?editors=1011

See that the alert is shown even if I don't trigger any selection, can I avoid this from happening?

Comment: looks like if on mounted makes the event to trigger
  mounted() {
    //this.selected = [1]
  },

Comment: yes, but I need to have an initial selection that is retrieved using an API call, but that selection should not trigger the input event

Comment: Maybe this is how it is suppose to work, whenever the selected array changes (programatically or user triggered), the input events should be triggered